# How can I evaluate the filename passed to a bash script via stdin

Tags: bash

I would like to evaluate a filename passed to a script via stdin and then use this in a sed command. At the moment I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval file="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
echo "$file"
sed -i -r ':a; s%(.*)/\*.*\*/%\1%; ta; /\/\*/ !b; N; ba' "$file"
```

Calling this as:

```
bash callfile < file.txt
```

results in the following error:

```
/dev/stdin
sed: couldn't open temporary file /dev/sedSVVTdr: Permission denied
```

Why is this code unable to read the filename I pass to it?

Comment: Looks like you're asking `sed` to do an in-place replacement in `/dev/stdin`. Where would it write the result?

Comment: You set `file` to the actual string `/dev/stdin` Sed can't know that you mean to read from standard input.

Comment: This is exactly the question. How to I get eval `file="${1:-/dev/stdin}"` to be set to "file.txt" rather than "/dev/stdin" without explicitly setting it in the script?

Comment: Have you tried `bash callfile file.txt` (without the `<`). It seems to me that is what you actually want. In this case `file.txt` is the first parameter `${1}`. Of course the `/dev/stdin` as a default if no filename is given still won't work, as the others explained. edit: I just saw that @jraynal mentioned it at the end as well.

Comment: @218 You can't really use both `-i` *and* `<`.

Answer (score 1):

That data is getting passed to you as a stream redirected from the file. Your script won't have any knowledge of that file - only the stream. As a further example, it could be data piped in from the output of another process, and so you wouldn't have any file to begin with.

Comment: If I set eval="file.txt" then this works. What I want to do is replace "file.txt" with a filename that I specify in stdin so that I don't have to change this in the code for every file I want to apply this script to.

Answer (score 1):

As @Brian Agnew said, you are reading from your document, so a good use of your command line is:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo ${line} | sed -r ':a; s%(.*)/\*.*\*/%\1%; ta; /\/\*/ !b; N; ba'
done < ${1:-/dev/stdin}
```

Note that is you have a list of files in a file, you can then run your process as intended:

```
./callfile < files_list.txt

while read -r file; do
    sed -i -r ':a; s%(.*)/\*.*\*/%\1%; ta; /\/\*/ !b; N; ba' "${file}"
done < ${1:-/dev/stdin}
```

but at the moment, there is no advantage of reading from `stdin`, so:

```
./callfile "file.txt"
```

EDIT: replaced `${line}` in the `read` by `line`, and `${file}` with `file`

I hope we understood your question.

Comment: What format does files_list.txt need to take. If I try this I just get `sed: can't read : No such file or directory.` If I put an additional line `echo "${file}"` in thie loop, I just get a blank line, so it's obviously unable to read any of the filenames I've provided.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. I always make this mistake!